# How many keys must a B-Tree Node have?

Tags: data-structures, b-tree

I am trying to implement a B-tree and I've read this article:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-of-b-tree-2/

These are two points that they wrote:

- Every node except the root must contain at least t-1 keys. The root may contain a minimum of 1 key.
- All nodes (including root) may contain at most (2*t – 1) keys.

*t* is normally a value that depends upon disk block size.

Then they gave an example with an arbitrary values *t* of 5 and drew this:

[image: photo]

**What I don't understand is,** they said that every node, except the root must contain ***at least t-1 keys***. In this example, t is 5, but none of the nodes have **at least (t-1)=4*** keys.

Comment: No worries. You just found yet another example where GeeksForGeeks has bad quality articles. Better look at reputable sources.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations ?

Comment: That really depends on what level you need, but ["CLRS"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) is considered a bible on algorithms and data structures. But for quick look up, Wikipedia performs better than GeeksForGeeks in my experience.